# Is there a way to identify every android device as a unique device?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way to identify every android device with a unique ID? What I mean is can I programmatically read a unique ID of a device that is running android. It doesn't matter if the format of the unique ID varies across hardware platform ( phones and including tablets), but as long as it is unique, reliable, and always accessible, it will work for me. I am currently using TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId() for phones which is working fine till now but I don't know what I should do for tablets. Should I use SECURE.ANDROID_ID? Is it reliable for expanding the usage of my app to android tablets? I have also heard on other posts that on many phones ANDROID_ID is same and also that it comes as a null sometimes. Can anyone give me a concrete solution to this problem?

Comment: I especially like the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/5626208#5626208

Comment: all those posts are 2 to 3 years old. Is there any update on this topic???

Comment: The answer I specifically linked to is 1 year old only (updated May 2012) and this information by its nature is still valid, last years devices are still around.